# Envio de arquivos PDF e JPEG com Jquery/ajax

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, upload

estou tentando implementar um upload de arquivos em pdf ou jpeg com ajax do jquery e não estou tendo sucesso, então estou precisando de uma ajuda se possivel.

Tentando utilizar o jquery em conjunto com o PHP, mas nao consigo passar os dados

> JS

```
$('#form-almoxarifado input[type=file]').ace_file_input({
      style:'well',
      btn_choose:'Escolha os arquivos aqui ou clique para escolher',
      btn_change:null,
      no_icon:'icon-cloud-upload',
      droppable:true,
      thumbnail:'large'
    }).on('change', function(){

      console.log('teste');
      console.log($(this).data('ace_input_files'));
      //console.log($(this).data('ace_input_method'));

    });
```

O codigo PHP esta funcionando que já testei aqui um upload individual

> PHP

```
    $conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "","teste");
    mysqli_set_charset($conn,"utf8");

    $arquivo    = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
    $nome       = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
    $tamanho    = $_FILES["file"]["size"];


    $fp = fopen($arquivo,"rb");//Abro o arquivo que está no $temp   
    $documento = fread($fp, $tamanho);//Leio o binario do arquivo
    fclose($fp);//fecho o arquivo

    $dados = bin2hex($documento);

    $sql = "INSERT INTO upload_arquivos (nome, tamanho, conteudo, data) VALUES ('$nome','$tamanho','$dados',now())";

    $result = $conn->query($sql)or die(mysqli_errno());
```

Comment: Porque que usas js para o upload? @Thiago Lopez

Comment: È de um framework que utilizamos na empresa, ela é toda em jquery e bootstrap com um visual agradavel e cheia de recursos ... mas esta parte seria mais pela estilização mesmo, estou tentando conversar entrar o objeto e codigo php.

Comment: Então podes sempre usar um `<form>`para inserires o ficheiro
Aconcelho te a ver este site 
[lW3](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp)

Answer (score -1):

Experimenta usar este tipo de código e use um `<form>` para fazer o upload

```
<?php
$target_dir = "uploads/";//upload paste
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}
// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check file size
if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 500000) {
    echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
&& $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
    echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
}
?>
```